# PHP Script gives memory exhausted error while running on 40000 files

Tags: php, csv

I'm using PHP to cut out the first row of about 40000 CSV's using array_shift I've run in to the following error:

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SeeClickFix/Finished_before_shift/shift.php on line 10
```

The script looks like this:

```
<?php
// Read the file
for ($x = 0; $x <= 40000; $x++) {

    $file = fopen('export'.$x.'.csv', 'r');

    // Iterate over it to get every line 
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        // Store every line in an array
        $data[] = $line;
    }
    fclose($file);

    // Remove the first element from the stored array / first line of file being read
    array_shift($data);

    // Open file for writing
    $file = fopen('export'.$x.'.csv', 'w');

    // Write remaining lines to file
    foreach ($data as $fields) {
        fputcsv($file, $fields);
    }
    fclose($file);

    echo $x;
}
?>
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated as I've never seen anything like this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the size of files?

Comment: instead of read csv into array, remove first element then save,  just remove first line as text file could save much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to empty the `$data` array before reading each file. Otherwise, it accumulates the lines from all the files.

```
<?php
// Read the file
for ($x = 0; $x <= 40000; $x++) {

    $file = fopen('export'.$x.'.csv', 'r');
    $data = array();

    // Iterate over it to get every line 
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        // Store every line in an array
        $data[] = $line;
    }
    fclose($file);

    // Remove the first element from the stored array / first line of file being read
    array_shift($data);

    // Open file for writing
    $file = fopen('export'.$x.'.csv', 'w');

    // Write remaining lines to file
    foreach ($data as $fields) {
        fputcsv($file, $fields);
    }
    fclose($file);

    echo $x;
}
?>
```

But if you just want to remove the first line from each file, you don't need to parse it as CSV. You can do it like this:

```
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 40000; $x++) {
    $file = fopen('export'.$x.'.csv', 'r');
    fgets($file); // Read first line
    $lines = stream_get_contents($file); // Read remaining lines
    fclose($file);

    file_put_contents('export'.$x.'.csv', $lines);
    echo $x;
}
?>
```